# How to find this path ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

Tags: macos, jupyter

Because I can't open my Jupyter

it show

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8890/?token=006f1d3a1045d356d73a63650f0ca05aa4fe786a24a52e72
0:97: execution error: "http://localhost:8890/tree?token=b322d4e463b5458e6545c58e49120e1a7081d36e01c6f531" doesn’t understand the “open location” message. (-1708)

so I google this solution is I need to go to

~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

on my mac and edit the file

but I don't know how to go the ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py ...

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to show hidden files on your Mac. `.jupyter` is a hidden folder in your Home directory.